# JavaScriptではコールバック関数はすべて非同期処理になるのか？

Tags: javascript, 非同期

JavaScriptの非同期処理についての質問です。

技術書や各々の解説ブログでは「コールバック関数は非同期処理」であると書かれています。
そこで以下のコードを実行してみたところ、自分のイメージしていた通りの結果になりませんでした。

```
function a(callback) {
  console.log('a');
  callback();
  console.log('finish');
}

function b() {
  for(let i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}

a(b);
```

関数aの中で関数bを呼び出しています。
この場合、関数bはコールバック関数なので、非同期処理になるというのが
今の自分の理解です。

そのため関数bの処理が完了するのを待たずに

```
console.log('finish');
```

が実行されるものと考えていました。

■想像していたconsoleの結果

> a
> finish
> 1
> 2
> ...
> 100

■実際のconsoleの結果

> a
> 1
> 2
> ...
> 100
> finish

関数bがコールバック関数で非同期に処理されるなら
bの処理の完了を待たず後続の

```
console.log('finish');
```

が処理されると思っていましたがそうではありませんでした。

自分の理解がどこか間違っていると思うのですが、それがわかりません。

どなたか、JavaScript初心者にコールバック関数と非同期処理について
ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 技術書や各々の解説ブログでは「コールバック関数は非同期処理」であると書かれています。

どこにどのように書いてあったのか分かりませんが、誤解があるのではと思います。

質問のコードは 100% 同期です (function a に書いた順番に上から下に実行される)。たとえ、function b の中で setTimeout を使って待つようなことをしても、function a では callback(); の完了を待って console.log('finish'); が実行されます。

function b を非同期にしたいということであれば、プロミスベースのメソッドにしてはいかがですか？

例えば以下のような感じです。

```js
function a(callback) {
    console.log('a');
    callback();
    console.log('finish');
}

// a が b を呼ぶと、b は Promise オブジェクトを生成して即座に戻り値として返す。

// Promise コンストラクタの引数の executor 関数（下のコード例では (resolve) => { ... } 
// が該当）は new Promise の時点で自動的かつ即座に実行される。

// executor 関数内の setTimeout により 2 秒後に for ループが動いてコンソールに出力される

function b() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
                console.log(i);
            }
            // function a で callback(); を await する場合はこれを呼び出さないと
            // 止まってしまうので注意
            resolve();
        }, 2000)
    });
}

a(b);
```

結果は:

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ありがとうございます。
『改訂3版 JavaScript本格入門』のPromiseオブジェクトの説明ページ冒頭に
「JavaScriptで非同期処理を実施する場合、古典的なアプローチの1つとしてコールバック関数があります」
と書かれているので、コールバック関数を使えば非同期処理にできると思っていました。

Comment: 例えば、HTMLCanvasElement: toBlob() メソッド https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob のようなケースのことを言っているのでしょうかね？　toBlob メソッドは非同期で動き、結果の Blob データは引数のコールバックに渡されるのですが。

Comment: 上記の技術書の中では、別ページでsetTimeoutの解説に合わせて非同期処理について簡単に触れています。   
なのでおそらく暗にsetTimeoutのことを指しているのではないかと思います。    
先述の通り、非同期処理を実施する場合コールバック関数があると書かれているせいで、すべてのコールバック関数が非同期処理になるものと、勘違いしました。非同期処理についてはQiitaやZeenにある記事を参考に学習していますが、なかなか奥深くて難しいです......

Answer (score 1):

コールバック関数が必ず非同期に呼ばれるということはありません。その関数 `a()` は同期的にコールバック関数を呼んでいるので非同期ではありません。同期か非同期かはコールバック関数を受け取る関数の仕様次第です。

非同期に起きる何かに反応して関数を呼びたいなら非同期にコールバック関数を呼ぶでしょうし、内部動作のカスタマイズをする目的なら同期でコールバック関数を呼ぶことが多いでしょう。`addEventListener()` `Promise` は前者、`forEach()` `filter()` は後者の例になります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。技術書をきちんと読み解けなかったのか、
「コールバック関数 = 非同期」だと思っていました。